# Resharper, new line after autocomplete

Tags: resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I often find myself in situation when I type something and autocomplete adds closing bracket and ; but I still have to add parameters, and when I'm finished with that, I would like to jump to new line.
Is that possible with some shortcut?

Example:

```
GL.ClearColor( -> autocomplete adds ); and puts the cursor inside  => GL.ClearColor(|);
GL.ClearColor(Color.Black|); -> now I've finished typing and my cursor is still inside, 
                            behind the last bracket, but I want to jump outside to new line
```

I'm using Resharper 7 in VS2010.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Complete Statement (also known as Smart Enter)](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Complete_Statement):

> Complete Statement, introduced in ReSharper 4, is a feature that
>   inserts necessary syntax elements (braces, semicolons etc.) and gets
>   you to the position to start the next statement, saving you from
>   excessive juggling with the caret. As you work, keep in mind the
>   default shortcut for this feature:
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> Complete Statement (also known as Smart Enter) comes to rescue in
>   numerous scenarios, including auto-closing parentheses, adding
>   semicolons, completing if, while and for statements, and so on.